# IMEI код на планшетах без 3G

Tags: android, imei

Здравствуйте. Есть программа, где мне нужно получить IMEI код устройства. Проверял на многих девайсах, но сегодня обнаружил, что его нельзя получить на устройствах без 3G (и соответственно без dialer'а). Получал его таким способом.

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String l1 = tm.getDeviceId();
```

На таких устройствах ничего не выдает. Сталкивался ли кто-нибудь с такой проблемой и как ее можно обойти?

P.S. честно говоря, я даже в настройках устройства не нашел его.

Comment: его нету там, где нету радиомодуля [WiKi](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMEI)

Comment: Я даже больше скажу: где сим-карт две и более, два и более IMEI. Наводит на мысли? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Сталкивался ли кто-нибудь с такой проблемой

Да, для самого однажды это было неожиданно.

> P.S. честно говоря, я даже в настройках устройства не нашел его.

Все верно, Устройства не имеющие слота под сим-карту, не имеют **радиомодуля**, следовательно не имеют и **IMEI**.

> как ее можно обойти?

Использовать в этом случае вместо`IMEI`, какой либо другой **псевдо**-уникальный идентификатор. Например:

```
String id = Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Comment: Всё-таки является ли данный id уникальным?

Comment: @ahgpoug да если не брать во внимание большое количество китайских поделок и возможность с рутом менять практически все, то вполне себе уникальный...опать таки нужно рассматривать в разрезе задачи, которую Вы решаете.

Comment: Но тогда и IMEI код нельзя считать уникальным из-за возможности его замены.

Comment: @ahgpoug вот вот, так что это уже такой философский вопрос про уникальность чего либо)